# I am having errors with checkout on wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, errors

> `Notice: tax_class was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Cart_Session->get_cart_from_session, WC_Cart->calculate_totals, WC_Cart_Totals->__construct, WC_Cart_Totals->calculate, WC_Cart_Totals->calculate_fee_totals, WC_Cart_Totals->get_fees_from_cart, WC_Cart->calculate_fees, do_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, TM_Extra_Product_Options->tm_calculate_cart_fee, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong.`

**This is the error i am experiencing, please how do i solve this?**

Comment: When did this error happen? did you update a plugin/theme? installed a new plugin maybe. Try disabling every plugin one by one or switching to a wordpress theme, if the problem still happens try contacting woocommerce on their forum

Comment: okay thanks will do that sir

Comment: I'd guess you need to update the TM_Extra_Product_Options plugin, which looks like [it's this](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619)?

Comment: However that's not an error, and if you're seeing it on checkout you can probably silence it by turning off WP_DEBUG in wp-config. But you do still need to update the plugin to fix it, else things might just break at some point in the future - silencing the notice is not a fix. I expect the checkout completed OK though.

Comment: @Rup it solved it, thanks alot and i have updated the plugins. everything is working fine now